# MySQL Search Field of File Paths

Tags: mysql, select, field

I have a field in a mysql table called "path" and it stores a file directory tree like this:

```
home/
home/myfile.txt
home/folder1/
home/folder1/myotherfile.txt
home/folder2/
home/folder2/evenmorefiles.txt
```

Lets say I want to get a list of paths for a specific path (much like you would cd into a directory and do a ls in linux). 
For example, show all rows in "home/" directory but not sub-directories

```
home/myfile.txt
home/folder1/
home/folder2/
```

My query works but its pretty ugly. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

```
SELECT path FROM myTable WHERE (path LIKE "home/%") AND (path NOT LIKE "home/%/%");
```

Comment: Why is it ugly?

Comment: Why not use regex with negation?

Comment: @juergen_d it is sorta slow on 2 million records. and SMA i am rusty on regex. always looks like a Japanese to me,,, but i figured that was the solution. thanks to Tim for the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE path REGEXP 'home/[^/]+/?$';

path
1   home/myfile.txt
2   home/folder1/
3   home/folder2/
```

### Demo

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for and +1 for that rextester site, very nice.

Comment: There's a problem with this if you want to find the root path. removing the home/ shows all the files.

Comment: @MarcPope I am not sure I follow your comment.  Does this work: `^myfile.txt$` ?  If you have a substantially different requirement you may want to open a new question.

Comment: using your regex, which works perfect for any path except doesn't work if you want to get the root path to see all the files at the highest level.

Comment: If you want all files/folders at the highest level then use the pattern `^[^/]+/?`.